# Java object-oriented design for RPG

Tags: java

I started creating a roleplaying as my first java project. I won't show you the code I have, but just an extremely simple version of it so it would be easier to explain and show what exactly it should be done. Here we go - we have an input from the user that contains a string of his chosen character class (Fighter or Rogue in this case), and we want to create a new character, our hero. The character has 3 fields: character class (according to the input) and attack and defense. Now I want to store initial stats of attack and defense for Fighter and Rouge, so the code can call Character(chosenCharacterClass) and create the character with  the right stats. How it should be done ? The code is very simple so it would be easy to edit. Just keep in mind that I have much more than 2 stats, so the solution should be good for a long stats-list (most of it would be int but it's plausible that I'll have some booleans), so avoid using enums (and avoid inheritance, I don't think that making Character an abstract class is the best solution here). Thanks!

```
public class Game {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Character hero = CharacterCreator.createCharacter();

    try {
        hero.displayCharacter();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }


}

}



public static Character createCharacter() {
    System.out.println("Choose a character: ");
    System.out.println("1. Fighter");
    System.out.println("2. Rogue");


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int scan = sc.nextInt();
    String chosenClass = getCharacterClass(scan);

    System.out.println("Choose Name:");
    Scanner nameIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = nameIn.next();

    Character hero = null;

    switch (chosenClass){
        case "Fighter":

            break;
        case "Rogue":

            break;
        case "def":
            System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }

    return hero;
}

    public static String getCharacterClass(int scan){

    String classIn;

    switch (scan) {
        case 1:
            classIn = "Fighter";
            break;
        case 2:
            classIn = "Rogue";
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Enter again");
            classIn = "def";
    }

    return classIn;
}
}


public class Character {

    private String characterClass;
    private int attack;
    private int defense;


    protected Character(String characterClass){
    setCharacterClass(characterClass); 
    setAttack();
    setDefense();

    }


    public String getCharacterClass() { return characterClass; }
    public int getAttack() { return attack; }
    public int getDefense() { return  defense; }


    protected void setCharacterClass(String characterClass) { this.characterClass = characterClass; }
    protected void setAttack(int atck){ attack = atck}
    protected void setDefense(int dfns){ defence = dfns; }

}
```

Comment: displayCharacter should print the 3 fields in Character but I deleted the method from Character, it's not important.

Answer (score 1):

Object-oriented way would be to make characterClass a class, and make use of polymorphism e.g. (following is a pseudocode java, it may not compile)

```
interface CharacterClass {
    String getName();
    CharacterStats getBaseStats();
}

public class Warrior implements CharacterClass{
    private CharacterStats = new CharacterStats(){{  //anonymous class with static initializer
        attack = 66;
        defense = 54;
        ...
    }}
    public String getName(){
        return this.class.getSimpleName();
    }

}

public class CharacterStats {
    public int attack;
    public int defence;
    ...
}

public class Character {

    private String characterClass;
    public CharacterStats stats;


...

    public setCharacterBaseStats(CharacterStats baseStats){
        this.stats = baseStats;
    }
}

Character npc1 = new Character();
...
npc1.stats.attack += 1;
```

Comment: That could be a good solution, I just have to think about the implementation. I had CharacterClass as an abstract class, but I had lots of code duplication between Character and CharacterClass (fields, getters/setters), and it was a bad design.Your solution is a bit different because you used CharacterStats class and implemented it in a different way. This way I won't have such a code duplication ?

Comment: I see your point now. The duplication you mentioned is called forwarding, it is considered good for encapsulation, but if you want to minimize code overhead, I would suggest to simply use fields instead of accessors (getter/setter pair). I made adjustments to the answer, where CharacterStats are Character public field, so they can be accessed easier and there is less overhead when adding new character statistics (new fields to CharacterStats).

Comment: Quite possibly an abstract base class would work better here

Comment: @KrystianLaskowski - I want to keep the fields as private, rather than giving free access to those fields. Using  public would make it easier to code, but the those  fields won't be safe.

Comment: I want to change stats just by accessing Character, it looks like CharacterStats can't guarantee safety here.

Comment: Then, I guess, the only viable solution is to create abstract class, containing CharacterStats with stats as private fields, and getters/setters. It may be Character class, or its parent class, depending on your design. It cannot be achieved with Interface (as it cannot contain instance fields) nor so-called Traits (as they require forwarding - duplicate code you try to avoid).

Comment: That's bad news :( . I had CharacterClass as an abstract class, and Fighter/Rogue/Mage etc extended CharacterClass, so I created a subclass of CharacterClass first and then assigned it to Character. It was bad.... every addition of another stat required me to add two getters and two setters and make other adjustments twice.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a properties file like:

```
characters=Rogue,Fighter
character.Rogue.attack=15
character.Rogue.defense=7
character.Rogue.use_magic=false
character.Fighter.attack=12
character.Fighter.defense=13
character.Fighter.use_magic=false
```

You can read the properties file with the Properties class (Java Standard) or a resp. library like e.g. apache commons-configuration ( https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/ ) within your Character-constructor. Take the matching value and set it in the contructor.

Comment: it would make far more sense to use json or xml configuration here.

Comment: Yes, if the OP want's to use a more comples setup then I would suggest a JSON config file. I don't like XML because it's too "noisy" ;-). But it's allways a good idea to keep the thing as easy as possible. He could start with commons-config with properties files and switches to a json/xml reader/writer adapter if needed. commons-configuration provides such possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read full question, but what i understand is that You have Character (Warrior, Fighter) and each has property like (attack, defense).

So "Character", in itself is nothing. It is abstract.

```
public abstract class Character {
    private int attack;
    private int defense;

    public Character(int attack, int defense) {
        this.attack = attack;
        this.defense = defense;
    }

    public int getDefense() {
        return defense;
    }

    public void changeDefence(int alterDefence) {
        defense += alterDefence;
        if (defense < 0) {
            defense = 0;
        }
    }
    // similarly for attack 
}
```

Here is your Fighter

```
public class Fighter extends Character {
    public Fighter(int attack, int defense) {
        super(attack, defense);
    }
}
```

Similarly your Rogue.
Now think little more. What "Character" is doing??
Fight, Walk ... and so many. These are inteface
So now have interface IFight

```
public interface Fight<E extends Character> {
    public int fightStat (E char1);
}
```

Now "Character" is going to implement it.
So "Character" definition is now

```
public abstract class Character<E extends Character> implements Fight<E>{
....
```

And "Fighter" now has to implement method in it.

Comment: I can discern that you haven't read the whole question :) . This way your constructor will be filled with looooots of arguments, which isn't practical. Plus, it doesn't store initial stats for each character class.

Comment: Whenever you create character, you have to set initial stat in constructor.  I know that a lot of argument will be there like health, magic, walkspeed.... I love your question. I like RPG :D.  Design pattern are difficult to write in  first place but for long, almost zero work. Like if "Wizard" came late, just make new class of it and all done

Comment: In case you don't want to pass stat every time, create FACTORY for character creation. Say it "CharacterFactory", which contain  method "public static Character createCharacter(Enum characterType)"